# react native openpgp: very slow generation keys on devices

Tags: performance, react-native, key, rsa

I have a trouble with performance during generation of key 2048 bit via [react-native-openpgp](https://github.com/orhan/react-native-openpgp).
This process can spend from 3 minutes to 14-15 on devices.
I trying to know what exactly spend time.
It was BigInteger constructors in rsa generate method. 
(src/crypto/public_key/rsa.js)
call of new BigInteger() can spend from 2 to 5 minutes.

Smartphone:

- Android 6.0.1;
- ASUS Zenfone (ZD551KL);
- processor Qualcomm MSM8939 Snapdragon 615 + Adreno 405;
- RAM 3072MB.

Project dependencies:

- "react": "15.4.2"
- "react-native": "0.42.3"
- "react-native-openpgp": "^1.0.3"

Code snippet:

```
const optionsGenerateKey = {
    userIds: [{ name:'FirstName LastName', email:'first.last@gmail.com' }],
    numBits: 2048,
    passphrase: 'password',
};

console.warn('prepare random values...');
await openpgp.prepareRandomValues();

console.warn('keys generation...');
const start = Date.now();
const key = await this.generateKey(optionsGenerateKey);
const end = Date.now();
console.warn((end - start) / 1000);
```

Who had such a problem? Maybe I do something wrong?
Keys generation is very slow.
Grateful for help

UPDATE: Slow performance just because of JavaScriptCore in react-native

Comment: Topic updated. May be somebody find is useful